# MVC4 - JQuery AutoComplete - .autocomplete is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, autocomplete, asp.net-mvc-4

I am abviously missing something, but I keep getting this message when trying to add auto complete to a text box: .autocomplete is not a function

_Layout (Only the head section):

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
 <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/css")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

Index:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#searchTerm").autocomplete({
       source: "/Search/AutocompleteSuggestions",
       minLength: 3,
       select: function (event, ui) {
             if (ui.item) {
                $("#searchTerm").val(ui.item.value);
                $("form").submit();
             }
       }
      });
});
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))'
{
<input id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
}
```

I am pretty sure that the Jquery plugin is not loading correctly but I can't see why!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After scratching my head for an hour or so I found the problem, so here goes:

1. You must add your javascript to the @section Scripts {} section
2. I had to include the following packages: 
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

MVC4 ships with the correct JQuery files and the default configuration already includes the necessary packages.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You doesn't seem to have included the `jquery-ui-1.8.11.js` script which is where the `autocompete` method is defined. You have only included `jquery-1.6.2.min.js` which is required but not enough. Also I would recommend you using a bundle to combine and minify the required scripts and styles into a single file which reduces bandwidth and improves page load time:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/themes/base/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
```

Comment: Hi Darin,
Added missing reference but still no luck. (I also updated the snippet)

Comment: Inspect with FireBug and make sure that all scripts and styles are properly loaded and you are not getting 404 errors. I would recommend you to simplify at maximum and include only the strict minimum scripts (jquery and jquery.ui) to more easily narrow down the problem. Also don't hardcode urls as you did in your example. If you don't want to use bundles, at least use url helpers to ensure that the urls are correctly referenced. Once you have ensured that the 2 scripts are properly included make sure that there aren't any errors present in the javascript console. Anyway debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

> I am pretty sure that the Jquery plugin is not loading correctly

How you know pretty sure the jquery plugin is not loaded correctly? First you should stop messing the things by combining referencing scripts/styles directly and using `System.Web.Optimization` helpers(`@Scripts`, `@Styles`..).

Use any one of the approach. I suggest first you directly load the needed css and scripts using `Url.Content` and see everything works fine and if it is then replace them completely with `@Scripts` and `@Styles`.

To know much about bundling/minification refer this link

http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449320317/ch_ClientOptimization.html#_putting_asp_net_mvc_to_work

Comment: Hi Mark,
Thanks for the advice. This is only a pet project, but I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the file `BundleConfig.cs` is registering

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

and it causes problems with JQuery UI.  I changed it to:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"));
```

and it works.